# Mouse cursor turned into a "thick plus", cannot click but mouse can move

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I have Ubuntu 16.04. The last thing I remember typing into the terminal was `import python`
This was done by mistake and I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after to end that process.
I had `pip uninstall monary` maybe before that.

But right now, the mouse is stuck as a plus (imagine a plus made of corners of 4 adjacent squares with very slight space in between). It can't click, though the cursor can move anywhere in the screen.
I even tried an external mouse but the result is the same.

I am planning to restart my computer and it might solve the issue. But, I want to know what caused this, and if it happens again what should I do?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`import` is the command to create a screenshot, provided by the ImageMagick tool suite.

When you run

```
import something
```

as shell command, it will show you a crosshair cursor to select a rectangular area of the screen for capturing, and then save that as file `something`.

Now you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, which is the shortcut for freezing a process and returning to the command prompt in Bash. So `import` is still "running" (not exactly - it's frozen, but still existing) and didn't get a chance to exit or return control over the mouse and screen.

You have to continue the `import` process by e.g. thawing it and getting it back to the foreground of the shell using the `fg` Bash command. It will probably exit immediately then, otherwise you can terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Alternatively, you could also just kill the process by closing the parent terminal window/Bash session or using a command like `killall -KILL import`.

Comment: wow, you sir are a genius

Comment: By accident I've run python script as shell (it didn't had shebang), this solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: 'exit -f' also works if you don't care about the contents of the current terminal window.

Comment: Thanks for solving that problem.  But now I have the parent problem - I want to run a python script from the command line, but it will launch ImageMagick when it hits the import statement?  How do I get around this?

Comment: @Tharpa Either you have to manually run it with the correct interpreter (like e.g. `python3 path/to/my_script.py`) or you have to make sure your script has a correct "shebang", i.e. the first line of the file starts with `#!` followed by the path to the required interpreter (for Python 3 you would usually use `#!/usr/bin/env python3`).

Comment: Woot! Got this answer open without clicking anything. Who needs a mouse anyway....

Comment: Absolute genius!

Comment: So many upvotes, this must be common, thank you!

Comment: for real..genius

Comment: 3 years later I tab my way back to this same solution after making the exact same mistake again.

Comment: This just saved my ass.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time this problem occurs because of the conflict in python scripts import with Linux  "import" command, I encountered this problem several times, and I used to adopt an easy solution.

```
type "bg" on your terminal
then "Cnt + c"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the terminal session alive. You can use **bg** command to get back to the last command you ran. Once you get the process back in terminal just stop it by using **ctrl + c**.

If the terminal session isn't live you can kill the process by using **ps -ax | grep "command name"** once you have the process id, you can kill it using the command, **kill pid**.